# MySql Update Running Very Slow

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Relative newby to sql. I'm trying to run a simple update, and it's taking quite a bit of time (keeps timing out at my current limit of 20 minutes). t1 has a few hundred thousand rows and t2 is notably smaller. Any way to tidy up the query so it runs faster, or is this on par for the size of my tables?

```
UPDATE listing_property_details AS t1
INNER JOIN location_data AS t2 ON t1.Address_Key = t2.Address_Key
SET t1._latitude = t2.Latitude,
    t1._longitude = t2.Longitude
WHERE t1._latitude IS NULL;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your question with the table declarations for listing_property_details and location_data.

Comment: Is `Address_Key` unique in each table?

Comment: why redundantly store lat/long in listing_property_details at all? it already exists in location_data and you have demonstrated that they can be joined.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

@FanoFN, I think you're onto something. In theory it should be unique, but when I checked it isn't forced to be unique and duplicates have snuck their way in.

Comment: @Paul Maxwell, each of these two tables store the data from separate API responses. We perform this particular join frequently enough that it notably slows down our runtime. I know it's redundant, but we need to optimize for runtime. I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but that's why.

Comment: @nnichols, I have to expose my naivete and confess I don't know what you mean by table declarations.

Comment: The CREATE TABLE statements. The EXPLAIN output for your query would be useful too. Just run the query with EXPLAIN before SELECT ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @FanoFN, we realized that Address_Key was not specified as the primary key in location_data, and the values were NOT unique. After fixing this and removing duplicates, it runs great.

The JOIN is much faster as well, so we may not need to create the redundant data in the first place, per @PaulMaxwell's comment.

Thanks for everyone's help.